# Fetch and display API information using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, carousel, web-api-testing

```js
fetch("https://wptavern.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts")
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    } else {
      throw new Error("NETWORK RESPONSE ERROR");
    }
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    displayDetails(data);
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error("FETCH ERROR:", error));

//*function displayDetails(data) {
  const informations = data[0]; //create a variable and store the array you need to access
  const informationsDiv = document.getElementById("informations"); //create a vaiable with a div to display the data

  const informationsTitle = informations.title.rendered; //create a variable and access the specific data, title in this case
  const heading = document.createElement("h1"); //create a heading variable h1
  heading.innerHTML = informationsTitle;
  informationsDiv.appendChild(heading);

  const informationsImage = document.createElement("img"); //create a variable for the image
  informationsImage.src = informations.episode_featured_image; //specify the image source inside the array
  informationsDiv.appendChild(informationsImage);

  const informationsDate = informations.date; //create a variable and access the date
  const heading1 = document.createElement("p"); //create a variable to use in the DOM
  heading1.innerHTML = informationsDate;
  informationsDiv.appendChild(heading1); //append the data
//}

function displayDetails(data) {
  let informationsDiv = document.getElementById("informations");
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let informations = data[i];
      let informationsTitle = informations.title.rendered;
      let heading = document.createElement("h1");
      heading.innerHTML = informationsTitle;
      informationsDiv.appendChild(heading);
      let informationsImage = document.createElement("img");
      informationsImage.src = informations.episode_featured_image;
      informationsDiv.appendChild(informationsImage);
      let informationsDate = informations.date;
      let heading1 = document.createElement("p");
      heading1.innerHTML = informationsDate;
      informationsDiv.appendChild(heading1);
  }
}
```

```css
.swiper {
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;
  }

.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size-adjust: 15px;
    background: #fff;
/* Center slide text vertically */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #c2bdd1;
}

.swiper-slide img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
html,body {
    
    height:100%;
    background: #eee;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#informations{
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 30px 12px 30px;
    color: rgb(252, 252, 252);
    background-color: #7766d7;
    border: 4px solid #9387f2;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  <!--Script-->
  <script src="script/script.js"></script>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper mySwiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper ">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div id="informations"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Swiper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
      allowTouchMove: true,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
      },
      keyboard: {
        enabled: true,
      }

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am building a carousel where on every page I want to display information (title, image, date) taken from this API: https://wptavern.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

So far I managed to write this script:

```
fetch("https://wptavern.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts")
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    } else {
      throw new Error("NETWORK RESPONSE ERROR");
    }
  }).then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    displayDetails(data);
  }).catch((error) => console.error("FETCH ERROR:", error));

function displayDetails(data) {
  const informations = data[0];
  const informationsDiv = document.getElementById("informations");
  const informationsTitle = informations.title.rendered;
  const heading = document.createElement("h1");
  heading.innerHTML = informationsTitle;
  informationsDiv.appendChild(heading);
  const informationsImage = document.createElement("img");
  informationsImage.src = informations.episode_featured_image;
  informationsDiv.appendChild(informationsImage);
  const informationsDate = informations.date;
  const heading1 = document.createElement("p");
  heading1.innerHTML = informationsDate;
  informationsDiv.appendChild(heading1);
}
```

The problem is, this works only on the first slide. If I try to call the same function for slide n2 and change all the variables and the start of the array, from data[0] to data[1], then slide n1 doesn't showcase info anymore, but slide n2 does!

I also added a picture of HTM because I don't know how to format code properly and stack overflow is not allowing me to post the question.

The end result should display all the recent articles provided by the API.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Read this to learn how to add a runnable code snippet in your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers

It will help a lot on understanding your question

Comment: Do you want to print them all at once, to have them all available in the screen, or change the displayed info when the carousel page changes?

Comment: So the idea is to change the displayed info. For each page, one article should appear. So on Slide n1, I will get article[0], on slide n2 article[1], etc... I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your code, this should work:

```js
fetch("https://wptavern.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts")
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        throw new Error("NETWORK RESPONSE ERROR");
      }
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      displayDetails(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error("FETCH ERROR:", error));


  function displayDetails(data) {
    let informationsDiv = document.getElementById("slider");
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var slide = document.createElement("div");
      slide.className = "swiper-slide";
      var slideContent = document.createElement("div");
      slideContent.className = "informations";
      let informations = data[i];
      let informationsTitle = informations.title.rendered;
      let heading = document.createElement("h1");
      heading.innerHTML = informationsTitle;
      slideContent.appendChild(heading);
      let informationsImage = document.createElement("img");
      informationsImage.src = informations.episode_featured_image;
      slideContent.appendChild(informationsImage);
      let informationsDate = informations.date;
      let heading1 = document.createElement("p");
      heading1.innerHTML = informationsDate;
      slideContent.appendChild(heading1);
      slide.appendChild(slideContent);
      informationsDiv.appendChild(slide);
    }
  }
```

```css
.swiper {
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;
  }

.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size-adjust: 15px;
    background: #fff;
/* Center slide text vertically */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #c2bdd1;
}

.swiper-slide img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
html,body {
    
    height:100%;
    background: #eee;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.informations{
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 30px 12px 30px;
    color: rgb(252, 252, 252);
    background-color: #7766d7;
    border: 4px solid #9387f2;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  <!--Script-->
  <script src="script/script.js"></script>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper mySwiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper" id="slider">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Swiper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
      allowTouchMove: true,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
      },
      keyboard: {
        enabled: true,
      }

    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It basically creates a new `swiper-slide` for each result of the API, and appends it to your slider.

Comment: Thank you for your input. So, each slide should display only one article provided by the API. Meaning that on slide 1 article 1 will be displayed, then swipe on slide 2, and article n2 is being displayed. I think what you wrote is correct, however, I do not know how to separate the data which in this case is provided as one single flow of information. Now I have one article and half appearing on Slide 1

Comment: @Automatron76 Ok got it, I've updated the answer based on your code

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the result I wanted to achieve. For some reason everything is now displayed next to each other and If I add your correction. the code doesn't work in my local environment. I'll try to figure out what went wrong. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Automatron76 You're welcome :) Regarding the issues, I've copied the snippet from your question so it should work fine in your environment. A couple of ideas: check the css (I've changed `#informations` to `.informations`); Check the console for js errors. If you still have issues open another question and I'll check.